# oracle pl/sql FORALL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am confused with this program pls explain any one line by line and must in forall loop   how i variable can iterate there

```
DECLARE
 TYPE mysubs_type IS TABLE OF pls_integer INDEX BY pls_integer;
 TYPE mylist_type IS TABLE OF pls_integer INDEX BY pls_integer;
 mysubs mylist_type;
 mylist mylist_type;
BEGIN
 mylist(2) := 2;
     mysubs(10) := 2; -- point to mylist(2)
 mylist(3) := 3;
     mysubs(200) := 3; -- point to mylist(3)
 mylist(6) := 6;
     mysubs(30) := 6; -- point to mylist(6)
     mysubs(40) := 3; -- point to mylist(3)
 FORALL i IN VALUES OF mysubs
 INSERT INTO mynum_table(my_list) VALUES(mylist(i));
END;
```

Comment: Why not simply start reading the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS879

Answer (score 0):

`I` iterate through the `bounds_clause` : `IN VALUES OF` indicating that `i` are the elements of `mysubs` and will iterate the collection `mysubs` in a way non consecutive. Here, in this case 4 times. respecting the index of `mysubs`:

- mysubs(10) : 2
- mysubs(30) : 6
- mysubs(40) : 3
- mysubs(200) : 3

The FORALL always inserted the block :

```
2
6
3
3
```